# Replicating data from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2005 - temporary solution

Tags: sql-server, replication, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I will be installing a new SQL Server 2014 database system, which is based on our current SQL Server 2005 database system.

The new system will be on a completely new infrastructure when we go live, leaving the current infrastructure available for rollback should we encounter any issues.

The business requires that a rollback option be available for 2 weeks minimum. Therefore in the event of a disaster scenario we would be required to switch back to the SQL Server 2005 database system. So the challenge I have is replicating the data upon going live with the SQL Server 2014 database system.

I am looking for a way to replicate the data (not necessarily the schema) from the SQL Server 2014 system to the SQL Server 2005 system.

I am not really a fan of SQL Server Replication and my preference is not to use this. My understanding is that this is not an option for us anyway due to the versions being too far apart, and therefore not supported.

I want to reach out to the community to find out if any tools are available to achieve this type of replication.

It may be possible for us to implement a schema change freeze if this helps in finding the right solution.

Please can you advise what options are available to us, if any? Or should we look to develop a bespoke system internally?

Are you aware of any Microsoft partners that might achieve this for us through a solution already developed?